# jQuery: on submit ui.dialog shows, dialog button submits

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I`ve the following code. 
There is a dialog with terms loaded and it shows on a form submit.
Help me please to submit the form by the agree button in a dialog.

```
$(".terms").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  height: 400,
  width: 500,
  buttons: {
    "I agree": function() {
      return $("#new_user").submit();
    },
    "Don`t agree - Exit": function() {
      return $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});

$("#new_user").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return $(".terms").dialog("open");
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: _"Help me please to disable prevent on it and submit it."_ **WHAT?!** I don't know what kind of language it is, but it's definitely not English!

Comment: Ok sorry help me just to submit it using button ;)

Comment: Using which button? The submit button or another button?

Comment: Sorry i dont know if it's just me, or is your code doing an infinite loop on `i agree`? every time you submit the same dialog will appear again?

Comment: First the form prevents from submitting and opens a dialog. Then i want by clicking on agree button in dialog the form to be submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
buttons: {
    "I agree": function() {
      return $("#new_user").unbind("submit").submit();
    },
    "Don`t agree - Exit": function() {
      return $(this).dialog("close");
    }
```

.unbind("submit").submit(); Will help to submit the form in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exaqctly what you want but maybe this helps. To prevent the default action you must be inside the submit function

```
$("#new_user").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    $(".terms").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, i`ve just misconverted it from .coffee that`s why there was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
>$("#new_user").submit(function(e) {
});
```

You have a totally empty function

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Then proceed refer to something which is out of scope (in scope only in the function block)

```
$(".terms").dialog("open");
```

Then randomly open a dialog.

Place the two lines within the function block and return false and you should be a step further.

The next problem is that you're pretty much looping around by calling .submit on the same element you've just popped the terms dialog from. It's all a bit confused.

You probably need a "submit" button which pops the dialog which then calls submit on the form I'm guessing.